# Failed Aggregation on Tornado/Motor: yielded unknown object MotorAggregationCursor

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, tornado-motor

I'm having issue to execute MongoDB aggregation operation on Tornado. This is the code,

```
pipeline = [
   {'$match': {
       '$or': [
           {'owner.id': '56dfdaa4082024b9384c0055'},
           {'members.top.member.id':'56dfdaa4082024b9384c0055'}
       ]
   }},
   {'$sort': {'date_s': -1}},
   {'$skip': 0},
   {'$limit': 20},
   {'$project':{
      'created_at': 1,
      'name': 1,
      'id': '$_id',
      'group.group_id': 1,
      '_id': 0,
      'permission': 1,
      'owner': 1,
      'type': 1,
      'members.total': 1,
      'desc': 1,
      'declared': 1
  }}
]
cursor = yield db.activities.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The same command runs perfectly well on MongoDB management tool (I'm using MongoChef). But on the Python Tornado, using "yield" async operation, it throws exception as

```
yielded unknown object MotorAggregationCursor(<motor.core._LatentCursor object at 0x00000000042DEA58>)
```

any idea? I'm short of clue for further debug... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual [`.aggregate()`](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.aggregate) method is not itself "async". But the cursor iteration is.

So instead:

```
cursor = db.activities.aggregate(pipeline)
while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
    doc = cursor.next_object()
    print(doc)
```

Just like the docs say.